# Inverse Laplace. Searching for understanding.

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I already know the answer but I'm searching for an understanding or explanation of why it's the answer.

The question is: find the inverse Laplace transform of

$$X = \frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+1} $$

answer is $$x = \exp(-t)\cos(t)$$

my professor pretty much just said look at the laplace table and mix the $\frac 1 {s+a} = \exp(-at)$ and $\frac{s}{s^2+w^2} = \cos(wt)$ rows together because they 'look' similar to the equation in the problem. This explanation doesn't give me much understanding of why you get that answer or a concrete method to follow so i can answer similar questions. Hope you can give me some insight!

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, we have some mathjax tutorial which is how to do typesetting of equations and stuff. I showed how to do it this time. You can click "edit" to see how it's written or you can search for tutorial.

Comment: The inverse transform of $$\frac{s}{s^{2} + \omega^{2}} = \cos (\omega t)$$ There shouldn't be an $s^{2}$ in the numerator.

Comment: Yes @Mattos is right, seems to be a typo. I think you can use time-shift or time-delay property of Laplace transforms if you have learned it.

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Note that  $$      \frac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+w^2}$$            is $F(s+1)$ where $F(s) = \frac{s}{s^2+w^2}$ is the inverse laplace transform of $\cos (\omega t)$.

Due to the shift of $s\to s+1$ we get a factor of $e^{-t}$ in front of $ \cos (\omega t)$

Thus the final answer is $$ e^{-t}\cos (\omega t)$$

Comment: Which properties of the transform allow us to do this?

Comment: $e^{at} f(t) \to F(s-a)$ which is called a shifting theorem.

Comment: I thought the shifting theorem was $f(t-a) \to e^{as}F(s)$

Comment: It is the other around.

Comment: It's actually both. I was mostly fishing for why.

Comment: Yes, there are two shifting theorems, and for your question the first shifting theorem was applied.